# ffmpeg audio frame from directshow sampleCB imediasample

Tags: c++, qt, audio, ffmpeg, directshow

i use isamplegrabber sampleCB callback to get audio sample, i can get buffer and buffer length from imediasample and i use avcodec_fill_audio_frame(frame,ost->enc->channels,ost->enc->sample_fmt,(uint8_t *)buffer,length,0) to make an avframe , but this frame does not make any audio in my mux file! i think the length is very smaller than frame_size.
can every one help me please? or give me some example if it is possible.
thank you

this is my samplecb code :

```
     HRESULT AudioSampleGrabberCallBack::SampleCB(double Time, IMediaSample*pSample){   
        BYTE *pBuffer;
        pSample->GetPointer(&pBuffer);
        long BufferLen = pSample->GetActualDataLength();        
        muxer->PutAudioFrame(pBuffer,BufferLen);    
}
```

and this is samplegrabber pin media type :

```
    AM_MEDIA_TYPE pmt2;
    ZeroMemory(&pmt2, sizeof(AM_MEDIA_TYPE));
    pmt2.majortype = MEDIATYPE_Audio;
    pmt2.subtype = FOURCCMap(0x1602);
    pmt2.formattype = FORMAT_WaveFormatEx;
    hr = pSampleGrabber_audio->SetMediaType(&pmt2);
```

after that i using ffmpeg muxing example to process frames and i think i need only to change the signal generating part of code :

```
AVFrame *Muxing::get_audio_frame(OutputStream *ost,BYTE* buffer,long length)
{
    AVFrame *frame = ost->tmp_frame;
    int j, i, v;
    uint16_t *q = (uint16_t*)frame->data[0];

    int buffer_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, ost->enc->channels,
                                                 ost->enc->frame_size,
                                                 ost->enc->sample_fmt, 0);
//    uint8_t *sample = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(buffer_size);
    av_samples_alloc(&frame->data[0], frame->linesize, ost->enc->channels, ost->enc->frame_size, ost->enc->sample_fmt, 1);
    avcodec_fill_audio_frame(frame, ost->enc->channels, ost->enc->sample_fmt,frame->data[0], buffer_size, 1);

    frame->pts = ost->next_pts;
    ost->next_pts  += frame->nb_samples;

    return frame;
}
```

Comment: The question is not well-defined. You need to provide more data about your DirectShow capture, also code that attempt to write using libav.

Comment: its simple! i wanna grab a mediasample using directshow and make a avframe of it, i do this for video frames but i couldnt do so for audio frames.

Comment: yes. every one can help.

Answer (score 2):

The code snippets suggest you are getting AAC data using Sample Grabber and you are trying to write that into file using FFmpeg's libavformat. This can work out.

You initialize your sample grabber to get audio data in `WAVE_FORMAT_AAC_LATM` format. This format is not so wide spread and you are interested in reviewing your filter graph to make sure the upstream connection on the Sample Grabber is such that you expect. There is a chance that somehow there is a weird chain of filter that pretend to produce AAC-LATM and the reality is that the data is invalid (or not even reaching grabber callback). So you need to review the filter graph (see [Loading a Graph From an External Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390650) and [Understanding Your DirectShow Filter Graph](http://alax.info/blog/1678)), then step through your callback with debugger to make sure you get the data and it makes sense.

Next thing, you are expected to initialize `AVFormatContext`, `AVStream` to indicate that you will be writing data in AAC LATM format. Provided code does not show you are doing it right. The [sample you are referring to](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/muxing_8c-source.html) is using default codecs.

- Related reading: [Support LATM AAC in MP4 container](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3244)

Then, you need to make sure that both incoming data and your FFmpeg output setup are in agreement about whether the data has or does not have ADTS headers, the provided code does not shed any light on this.

Furthermore, I am afraid you might be preparing your audio data incorrectly. The sample in question generates raw audio data and applies encoder to produce compressed content using `avcodec_encode_audio2`. Then a packed with compressed audio is being sent to writing using `av_interleaved_write_frame`. The way you attached your code snippets to the question makes me thing you are doing it wrong. For starters, you still don't show relevant code which makes me think you have troubles identifying what code is relevant exactly. Then you are dealing with your AAC data as if it was raw PCM audio in `get_audio_frame` code snippet whereas you are interested in reviewing FFmpeg sample code with the thought in mind that you already have compressed AAC data and sample gets to thins point after return from `avcodec_encode_audio2` call. This is where you are supposed to merge your code and the sample.

Comment: yes my samplegrabber works correctly and i can save raw data to a file using c++ and play it. and that is right ,i'm using aac_latm in my sample grabber pin media type because of my incomming audio stream, and now i found out of your response that i have to use AV_CODEC_ID_AAC_LATM codec in my avformatcontext , but when i use this codec , avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id) returns "Could not find encoder for this codec! please help me. thank you